# Java Spark ML (Dataframe API) manual categorical assignment

Tags: java, apache-spark

Java Spark ML (Dataframe API) manual categorical assignment

I'm using Spark's Java API to run a random forest and I'm having issues setting up the data that has a mix of both categorical and continuous variables.

I have a Dataset that I'm loading from a parquet file that has Strings, Doubles, etc... that I want to convert into a dataset that I can use for a random forest.

I know I need to convert the data into a vector (via something like VectorAssembler) but the problem is the categorical variables. I don't know how to manually assign the vectors into categorical variables. I don't want to use one hot encoding (as I have some variables with 30+ categories) so I've instead used StringIndexer to create the categorical columns that go into the vector.

The key problem I'm having is that I can't use VectorIndexer()'s setMaxCategories() option to then setup the categorical variables as I have some columns that are doubles that have less than 30 unique values. My categorical variables also have varying levels of different levels.

I basically want a way to manually assign "which" columns (by index or however) will be the categorical ones and I can't find any way to do it. I'm sure there's some class or method that I'm missing here.

I figured out a "dumb" way to do it but there must be a better way. The "dumb" way is to:

1. For each individual String column

   - Run StringIndexer (creating a new column that has indexes instead of Strings)
   - Run VectorAssembler (creating a vector with only the 1 column from above)
   - Run VectorIndexer (using the single column vector input from above and putting an unreachably high value in setMaxCategories()
2. Combine all the single column vectors into one vector with all the columns.

There must be a better way to do this,... anyone have any ideas?